# Date arithmetic in Cognos 8

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

What I need is a data item expression which outputs the starting date of the current quarter of last year. Finding the current year is easy, as is subtracting 1 year from that date. But beyond that I get stuck.

I currently have an ugly `if` expression for each quarter like:

> if (extract(month,current_date) in (10,12,12))
>   then ((extract(year,_add_years (current_date,-1))||'-10-01'))

But no matter what I do I can't concatonate the year and date into string I can convert to a date object. The above code gives the error:

> The operation "add" is invalid for the following combination of data types: "integer" and "character"

Trying to cast the integer as a character using `cast()` I get this error. I also get this error when trying to turn a character array into a date:

> The operation "condexp" is invalid for the following combination of data types: "character" and "integer"

Trying to use SQL Server specific functions (it is a SQL Server database) just gives me an error that those functions are unavailable for local processing, so I can't seem to use SS date arithmatic, and I can't find anything particularly applicable in Cognos' built in date functions.

How can I manipulate a date to add a year to a known day/month combination and use that as a date object?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using cognos 10.1.1, but it would work.

You can get the value by using the following code:

```
_make_timestamp(
  extract(year, _add_years(current_date, -1)),
  (floor((extract(month,current_date)-1)/3)*3+1),
  01
)
```

The following is the simple way to get the starting month of the quarter.

```
(floor((extract(month,current_date)-1)/3)*3+1),
```

and you can convert timestamp to date or string.

```
cast(
  _make_timestamp(
  extract(year, _add_years(current_date, -1)),
  (floor((extract(month,current_date)-1)/3)*3+1),
  01
  ),
  date
)
```

,

```
cast(
  cast(
    _make_timestamp(
      extract(year, _add_years(current_date, -1)),
      (floor((extract(month,current_date)-1)/3)*3+1),
      01
    ),
    date),
    varchar(10)
)
```

plus, you can use extract function when you get a day value.

```
extract(day, _first_of_month (current_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with SQLSERVER built-in functions tht exists in Cognos. 
Here is an expression that works for me:

```
DATEADD({month},(3)*((DATEPART({quarter},[FullDateAlternateKey]))-1),
DATEADD({YEAR}, DATEDIFF({YEAR}, 0, dateadd({year},-1,[FullDateAlternateKey])), 0))
```

The FullDateAlternateKey field is my date field (from ADVERTUREWORKS DW DB). 
If you still have problems, try to isolate the problem by trying this expression on new simple list report.